# How do i clear all drawn graphics from the pictureBox1 without clearing the original image?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace mws
{
    public partial class ColorClouds : Form
    {
        private Bitmap _bmpBU = null;
        private Rectangle mRect;

        public ColorClouds()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            this.DoubleBuffered = true;
            _bmpBU = new Bitmap(@"D:\MyWeatherStation-Images-And-Icons\radar090.PNG");
        }

        private void ColorClouds_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.pictureBox1.Image = (Bitmap)_bmpBU.Clone();
            this.pictureBox2.Image = (Bitmap)_bmpBU.Clone();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (pictureBox1.Image != null)
            {
                ScanBmpFast((Bitmap)this.pictureBox1.Image, true, new Rectangle(40, 10, 20, 50));
                this.pictureBox1.Refresh();
            }
        }

        private unsafe void ScanBmpFast(Bitmap bmp, bool setToOpaqueYellow, Rectangle rect)
        {
            BitmapData b1 = bmp.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, bmp.Width, bmp.Height), System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageLockMode.ReadWrite, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);

            int stride = b1.Stride;
            int nWidth = bmp.Width;
            int nHeight = bmp.Height;

            System.IntPtr Scan0 = b1.Scan0;

            byte* p = (byte*)(void*)Scan0;

            int sX = Math.Min(Math.Max(rect.X, 0), bmp.Width);
            int sY = Math.Min(Math.Max(rect.Y, 0), bmp.Height);
            int w = Math.Min(rect.Width, bmp.Width - sX);
            int h = Math.Min(rect.Height, bmp.Height - sY);

            for (int y = sY; y < sY + h; y++)
            {
                p = (byte*)(void*)Scan0;
                p += (y * stride + sX * 4);

                for (int x = sX; x < sX + w; x++)
                {
                    if (p[0] != 0 || p[1] != 0 || p[2] != 0)
                    {
                        p[1] = p[2] = (byte)255;

                        if (setToOpaqueYellow)
                        {
                            p[0] = (byte)0;
                            p[3] = (byte)255;
                        }
                    }

                    p += 4;
                }
            }

            bmp.UnlockBits(b1);
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (pictureBox2.Image != null)
            {
                ScanBmp((Bitmap)this.pictureBox2.Image, true, new Rectangle(400, 100, 200, 500));
                this.pictureBox2.Refresh();
            }
        }

        private void ScanBmp(Bitmap bmp, bool setToOpaqueYellow, Rectangle rect)
        {
            BitmapData b1 = bmp.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, bmp.Width, bmp.Height), System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageLockMode.ReadWrite, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);

            int stride = b1.Stride;
            int nWidth = bmp.Width;
            int nHeight = bmp.Height;

            System.IntPtr Scan0 = b1.Scan0;
            IntPtr p = b1.Scan0;

            int sX = Math.Min(Math.Max(rect.X, 0), bmp.Width);
            int sY = Math.Min(Math.Max(rect.Y, 0), bmp.Height);
            int w = Math.Min(rect.Width, bmp.Width - sX);
            int h = Math.Min(rect.Height, bmp.Height - sY);

            for (int y = sY; y < sY + h; y++)
            {
                p = Scan0;
                p += y * stride + sX * 4;

                for (int x = sX; x < sX + w; x++)
                {

                    if (Marshal.ReadByte(p) != 0 || Marshal.ReadByte(p + 1) != 0 || Marshal.ReadByte(p + 2) != 0)
                    {
                        byte res = (byte)255;
                        Marshal.WriteByte(p + 1, res);
                        Marshal.WriteByte(p + 2, res);

                        if (setToOpaqueYellow)
                        {
                            Marshal.WriteByte(p, (byte)0);
                            Marshal.WriteByte(p + 2, (byte)255);
                        }
                    }

                    p += 4;
                }
            }

            bmp.UnlockBits(b1);
        }

        private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Image iOLd = this.pictureBox1.Image;
            this.pictureBox1.Image = (Bitmap)_bmpBU.Clone();
            if (iOLd != null)
                iOLd.Dispose();
        }

        private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Image iOLd = this.pictureBox2.Image;
            this.pictureBox2.Image = _bmpBU;
            if (iOLd != null)
                iOLd.Dispose();
        }

        private void ColorClouds_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
        {
            Image iOLd = this.pictureBox1.Image;
            this.pictureBox1.Image = (Bitmap)_bmpBU.Clone();
            if (iOLd != null)
                iOLd.Dispose();
            iOLd = this.pictureBox2.Image;
            this.pictureBox2.Image = _bmpBU;
            if (iOLd != null)
                iOLd.Dispose();

            if (_bmpBU != null)
                _bmpBU.Dispose();
        }

        private void pictureBox1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            using (Pen pen = new Pen(Color.Red, 2))
            {
                e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(pen, mRect);
            }
        }

        private void pictureBox1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
            {
                mRect = new Rectangle(mRect.Left, mRect.Top, e.X - mRect.Left, e.Y - mRect.Top);
                pictureBox1.Invalidate();
            }
        }

        private void pictureBox1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            mRect = new Rectangle(e.X, e.Y, 0, 0);
        }

        private void pictureBox1_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            if (pictureBox1.Image != null)
            {
                ScanBmpFast((Bitmap)this.pictureBox1.Image, true, mRect);
                this.pictureBox1.Refresh();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I did that i can draw rectangle over the picturebox1 and fill it with rectangle.
When i click on the pictureBox1 to draw over again the rectangle frame is clear but the draw it self inside the rectangle is not.

ScanBmpFast just fill the rectangle i draw with some color. 
This color is not clearing. Only the rectangle frame.
I want to clear it all and leave only the original image it self.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sigh. If you don't draw in the `Paint` (directly or on its `e.Graphics` which you may pass around) event nothing will persist.

So all you need to do to get rid of those non-persistent pixels is to call

```
pictureBox1.Invalidate();
```

Which of course leads to the question, what are you drawing and why don't you do it right? Anything drawn outside the `Paint` event will not only be deleted by the `Invalidate()` call you code but also by many outside events, like minimizing the `Form` etc..

Persistent drawing (unless you draw into the `Image`) will need to create data structures which hold the details of what to draw where and how, i.e. `Points, Rectangles, Brushes, Pens` etc..

And to delete such persistent drawing you clear those data..

So if you don't want the `Rectangle` to be drawn in the `Paint` event, don't do it! As long as you have the code there it'll always reappear.